# How to stop a merge (yet again....)

Tags: git, git-merge

How do I definitively stop Git from trying to merge? I ***never*** want it to merge.

From [How to make Git honor a cancelled merge that was not asked for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31312742), I know the tool does not respect my cancellation by killing the editor it spins up without asking me. So now I just `kill -9` the terminal process.

If I get into a situation where Git wants to merge, I always want the server's copy of the source file. I'll just delete the file locally and then fetch it again from the server.

---

Right now, Git is DoS'ing me with this piece of goodness:

> You have not concluded your merge (MERGE_HEAD exists).
>   Please, commit your changes before you can merge.

Of course, the `git reset HEAD <file>` did not work.

And here's the best part: they are the ***exact*** same file. There are ***no*** differences between them. I make a change, I test it on 8 to 12 different platforms (copying with `scp`), and then I check it in on one of those boxes after testing. But from [Tell Git to stop prompting me for conflicts when none really exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31108960/608639), I know the tool is too stupid to show any intelligence in this area.

---

If you are wondering, there is one set of sources. They are the project's sources located on the remote server. All I want Git to do is checkout (clone), update (pull), tell me what has changed (diff) and checkin (push). I don't need any other features from the tool.

Answer (score 4):

You could declare a [custom merge driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/930495/6309) for '`*`' (all files) in a `.gitattributes`, with a `keepTheir` script.

```
echo * merge=keepTheir > dirWithCopyMerge\.gitattributes
git config merge.keepTheir.name "always keep theirduring merge"
git config merge.keepTheir.driver "keepTheir.sh %O %A %B"
```

`keepTheir.sh` would be:

```
mv -f $3 $2
exit 0
```

---

> I need to get the server's copy of a file (and possibly meld changes). Under Subversion, I would use svn update

Easy: use [`git fetch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) (which won't trigger any merge), and then [`git checkout`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout):

```
git checkout origin/master -- path/to/file
```

(See "[git: how to update (checkout) a single file from remote origin master](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4427783/6309)")

Comment: @jww normally, a `git merge --abort` is enough to stop the merge.

Comment: It starts the process automatically when I do a `git pull`. I never do a `git merge`. I have ***never*** issued the command.

Comment: @jww git pull is git fetch + git merge, so that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks VonC. So maybe I should back up then. I need to get the server's copy of a file (and possibly meld changes). Under Subversion, I would use `svn update`. When I researched it in the past, I was told to use `git pull`. But it appears `git pull` may be the wrong tool for the job. What should I be using get the server's copy of a file (and possibly meld changes)?

Comment: @jww I have updated my answer, in order to not use git pull.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `.git/config`

```
[merge "keepTheir"]
   name = always keep their during merge
   driver = cp -f %B %A
```

and add this into your `.gitattributes`

```
public/dist/app.min.css merge=keepTheir
```