# How do I make Git always use "theirs/ours" for resolving conflicts in a particular file, during rebase?

Tags: git, git-rebase

I've created my own `dev` branch from a pretty active repository. This repository (Clappr) also contains a compiled and minified file, which is updated with the source code.

Whenever I want to rebase my `dev` branch with the `master`, this file is conflicting, because it cannot be automatically merged—of course, because it's a minified JS file:

```
$ git checkout dev
$ git rebase master
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: dummy commit
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
M   dist/clappr.js
M   src/playbacks/hls/hls.js
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging src/playbacks/hls/hls.js
Auto-merging dist/clappr.js
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in dist/clappr.js
```

I can resolve this conflict using `--ours`, but I have to do this for every single commit on `master` that I haven't rebased yet.

I know I can skip a patch entirely, but can I somehow automatically tell Git to ignore that `clappr.js` file and just always use whatever is in my `dev` branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a custom merge driver (as in "[Git: How to rebase many branches (with the same base commit) at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866218/git-how-to-rebase-many-branches-with-the-same-base-commit-at-once)" for a concrete example).

That merge driver "`keepMine`" associated with `dist/clappr.js`, and declare that merge driver in a `.gitattributes` file present in each of your branches.
See "[How do I tell git to always select my local version for conflicted merges on a specific file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928646/how-do-i-tell-git-to-always-select-my-local-version-for-conflicted-merges-on-a-s)".

```
echo clappr.js merge=keepMine > dist/.gitattributes
git config merge.keepMine.name "always keep mine during merge"
git config merge.keepMine.driver "keepMine.sh %O %A %B"
```

With `keepMine.sh` put somewhere in your `$PATH`, not in the repository:

```
# I want to keep MY version when there is a conflict
# Nothing to do: %A (the second parameter) already contains my version
# Just indicate the merge has been successfully "resolved" with the exit status
exit 0
```

(For a `KeepTheir.sh`, see "[How to stop a merge (yet again…)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31536537/6309)")

---

Even simpler, as noted by [`branch14`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3094876/branch14) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31560274/how-do-i-make-git-always-use-theirs-ours-for-resolving-conflicts-in-a-particul/31560423#comment112422725_31560423):

> Linux already has a command that successfully does nothing, aptly named "`true`".

```
git config merge.keepMine.driver "true"
```

Comment: Linux already has a command that successfully does nothing, aptly named "true". No need for `keepMine.sh`, just use `git config merge.keepMine.driver "true"`.

Comment: @branch14 Thank you. That must have slipped my mind when I wrote this 5 years ago. I have edited the answer to include your comment, for more visibility.