# Excluding files from Getting rebased

Tags: git

I have recently switched from `svn` to `git`.

After failed thorough grind up with google and its crawelers, please find my situation as below:

**Scenario**

I have added files in `.gitignore` to makes `git status` *silent* about the *untracked* files.

**Problem**

Problem is that every time i `rebase` my branch, this file is also getting overwritten and i am seeing all untracked files on console.

**Requirement**

Is there any way to do `git ignore <.gitignore_file>` so that this file is excluded from getting rebased / overwritten on any operation??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you commit the `.gitignore` file, I don't see why you should have this problem. But nothing stops you to add `.gitignore` itself to `.gitignore`

As for an alternative way to exclude files, you can create a file `.git/info/exclude` which acts as a local `.gitignore` outside of the working directory.

Comment: i thought `.gitignore` is for local machine...why should i commit it??

Comment: Because it isn't for the local machine. You should use it only to ignore files that will be present in all instances (like binaries or other generated files). To ignore files specific to your local instance, there is `.git/info/exclude`, and for files specific to your local machine (like `.DS_Store` on Mac or `desktop.ini` on Windows), there is `~/.gitignore`

Answer (score 3):

You can define a custom merge driver which would apply just to .gitignore, and always keep the local version.
See in "[Git: How to rebase many branches (with the same base commit) at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866218/git-how-to-rebase-many-branches-with-the-same-base-commit-at-once)" for a concrete example.

That merge driver "`keepMine`" can be associated with `.gitignore`, and be declared in a `.gitattributes` file present in each of your branches.
See "[How do I tell git to always select my local version for conflicted merges on a specific file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/928646/how-do-i-tell-git-to-always-select-my-local-version-for-conflicted-merges-on-a-s)".

```
echo .gitignore merge=keepMine > .gitattributes
git config merge.keepMine.name "always keep mine during merge"
git config merge.keepMine.driver "keepMine.sh %O %A %B"
```

With `keepMine.sh` put somewhere in your `$PATH`, not in the repository:

```
# I want to keep MY version when there is a conflict
# Nothing to do: %A (the second parameter) already contains my version
# Just indicate the merge has been successfully "resolved" with the exit status
exit 0
```

(For a `KeepTheir.sh`, see "[How to stop a merge (yet again…)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31536537/6309)")